# Prevent Android from generating new ID on resources

Tags: android, resources

Does anyone know if it is possible to make Android not generate new ID's for resources that is added to raw, drawable and other resource-folders?
The problem is that if I for example add an image with the name 3.jpg, and later on adds another image called 2.jpg the ID for image 3.jpg gets changed.
I need to keep the ID's static as the ID's are defined in XML files and used in the app to get the resources based on the ID.

I may have done something wrong when I tested it so it may be that the ID does not get changed, but as far as I can remember ID got changed when adding new resources.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you referring to the actual IDs in autogenerated R.java file? They are auto-generated and you cannot rely on them being constant. Instead of using the actual values of the IDs in your XML, try using Resource identifiers like R.id.myimage1, R.id.myimage3 etc.

Comment: @zeiger : Yeah, that's the IDs I'm reffering to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, R.java is autogenerated and all resource ID's are internally allocated by eclipse. Technically your code should not depend on the ID's generated. So even if ID's keep changing, it is absolutely fine. If you are depending on the generated ID's in your code, you will keep running into problems.

Comment: Okay, so should I use path names instead of ID's?

Comment: exactly, if you want to use images you can address them as R.drawable.image1 or something similar, The ID's thing becomes invisible to us here. Hence even if it changes, your code is not disturbed